# Alternatives for CSS floats for email clients

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, html-email

I'm trying to build a HTML email using foundation for emails which seems to have worked well however, I have discovered that outlook 2007+ doesn't like floats, does anybody know of a good alternative?

At the moment my elements are full width instead of floating to the left/right as they should!

Many thanks

Comment: Email marketing are basically done with Tables because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a few email marketings in the past months and I can say to you that the best way to build an email marketing is by having some notion of `table`s and spacers.

Here is a link for a basic tutorial about what I'm saying: [Simple Steps For Email Marketing](https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/how-to-code-an-email-newsletter/)

An email marketing is basically a sequence of `table` inside `table`s with a few blank `td`s usually by the class of spacer.

So here goes some tips that will make it work across all email clients having the tutorial I sent in mind, **although I will state that I have never used foundation**:

1. You will need to structure every part of your email inside tables.
2. Work with all your CSS inline.
3. Get used to creating spacer (blank tables) to simulate margins that you may then hide in mobile versions.
4. You need a service that lets you simulate how your email will look in every platform.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was rather hoping that Foundation for emails would make this less of a headache but has in fact caused more problems than it's solved! *Note to self...USE TABLES!!!!*

Comment: @Captain_Custard No problem. Its really something to get used to this system, but it works. But You'll have to always be learning a little more about each email platform. There is always something to be fixed in a different one. Outlook gave me huge headaches...

Comment: Outlook in particular uses microsoft word to format its emails to my understanding, so it puts all manner of garbage in there alongside your HTML... (How annoying!)